# Why 2-legged token is used to create new project in BIM360 not 3-legged token?

Tags: authentication, autodesk, forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

I was trying to create new project in BIM 360 using [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/account-admin/create-project/) API. I thought, to create new project it may need an end user to authorize my Forge app. So I user 3-legged bearer token to request new project. But gave forbidden response saying

```
{
    "code": 1003,
    "message": "Only support 2 legged access token."
}
```

Whereas by using 2-legged token, it created project successfully.

Why this API works with 2-legged and not with 3-legged token, even if 3-legged token is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-POST/), see `Authentication Context: app only`

At the moment of creating, there are no users on the project, therefore the 2LO key is required.